# SQL Multiple left Joins: A to B then A to C

Tags: sql

If I have 3 tables A, B and C I understand how to use left join to join them like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.col = B.col LEFT JOIN
     C
     on B.col = C.col
```

So A to B then B to C

How would I do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.col = B.col LEFT JOIN
     C
     on A.col = C.col
```

So A to B and then A to C

Would really appreciate any help

Comment: What is wrong with your syntax?  Sample data and desired results might help explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with what you're trying to accomplish.

A simple example is at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dbbe2/2

There are three tables (A, B, and C):

```
Table A
id  name
1   Alice
2   Bob
3   Carol
4   Don
5   Edith

Table B
id  id_A    pet
1   5   Tex
2   4   Socks
3   2   Rex
4   1   Percy
5   1   Quinlan

Table C
id  id_A    hobby
1   1   acting
2   2   boxing
3   4   dancing
4   5   eating
```

Tables B and C relate to Table A through the id_A foreign key.

A query like you have:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id_a LEFT JOIN C
ON A.id = C.id_a;
```

works just fine.